# Issue retrieving firebase child node swift

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

Xcode 9 - Swift 4

No Permissions set on Firebase Data - read/write everyone

I imported json data into firebase and my data looks like this..

[image]

I am trying to get to to the title of the jobs listed in FireBase Database, place the list of titles in an array and into a tableView and it will not return anything
My swift code looks like this..

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase


class PostViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var jobPostsTableView: UITableView!

    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle = 0


    var searchJSONQuery : String = ""

    var jobsData = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        jobPostsTableView.delegate = self
        jobPostsTableView.dataSource = self

        //Set the Firebase Reference
        ref = Database.database().reference()



    // Retreive the posts and listen for changes
        databaseHandle = (ref?.child("positions/title").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            //Code to execute when a child is added under "positions"
            //Take the value from the snapshot and add it to the jobsData array

            let list = snapshot.value as? String

            if let actualList = list {
                self.jobsData.append(actualList)
                self.jobPostsTableView.reloadData()
            }

        }))!


}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return jobsData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = jobsData[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }


}
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: @ibrahim Akar I've edited my answer, try it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @matias  ..not only did it lead me to the right place I actually learnt a lot .. there is one thing that was missing.. the child had to be casted

for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{

Answer (score 2):

When using `child()` you only go one level down the tree at the time. Because you have a lot of positions you can not simply access the titles by using `child("title")`.

When calling the observeSingleEvent you're looking for the *values* of the key you have stated in you database-reference.

The way written below you get a snapshot of all the values beneath your "positions" key. Therefore you use the for-loop to access the "title" value of every single object.

You should write it as a separate function and call it from viewDidLoad() rather than write the firebase code inside viewDidLoad itself.

```
func retrieveJobTitles(){

        let positionRef = ref.child("positions")

        positionsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            // Iterate through all of your positions
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

               let position = child as! DataSnapshot

               let positionsInfo = position.value as! [String: Any]

               let jobTitle = positionsInfo["title"] as! String

               if jobTitle != nil {
                  self.jobsData.append(jobTitle)
               }
            }

            self.jobPostsTableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though you're right with what you said, you actually didn't show him what he did wrong. The actual problem is the ''DataEventType'' he is using. Instead of using ".childAdded" he should use ".value".

Comment: @MassimilianoDelMaestro You're right. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I used the function suggested by matiastofteby - thanks

            // Iterate through all of your positions
            for child in snapshot.children {

I get the error: immutable value 'child' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it  - No data returned

Comment: Sorry I have updated it now. Also change `userInfo` to `positionsInfo`

Comment: I am now down to one error at this line..

let positionsInfo = child.value as! [String: Any]

Error: Value of type 'Any' has no member 'value'
Cast 'Any' to 'AnyObject' or use 'as!' to force downcast to a more specific type to access members

Comment: Sorry I have been writing all the code directly here in the browser so I missed some stuff. I think it should be alright now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @matiastofteby  ..not only did it lead me to the right place but I also learnt a lot .. there is one thing that was missing.. the child had to be casted

for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{

Comment: @ibrahimAkar glad I could help - I have updated the answer one final time! If you think it is worth it please consider marking the answer as accepted answer :=)